# Changing Zend_Db_Select's output to Zend_Db_Table_Rowset

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have the following code inside a class that extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`:

```
public function fetchByFriends($id) {
    /*
     * SELECT * FROM list 
     * INNER JOIN friendship ON 
     * list.user_id = friendship.friend_id
     * WHERE friendship.user_id = ?
     */

    $select = $this->select()
                   ->from("list")
                   ->join("friendship", "list.user_id = friendship.friend_id")
                   ->where("friendship.user_id = ?", $id);
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false); // allows joins within a DbTable

    $stmt = $select->query();
    return $this->fetchAll($stmt);
}
```

While the query works fine the data returned is of an array. Is there some way to refactor this so that `fetchAll` returns it as a `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset`, rather than an array?

Answer (score 0):

Poor research on my part. I found the answer in Zend's reference manual:

**[Advanced usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.advanced.usage)**

> **Example #27 Using a lookup table to refine the results of fetchAll()**
>
> ```
> $table = new Bugs();
>
> // retrieve with from part set, important when joining
> $select = $table->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
> $select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
>        ->where('bug_status = ?', 'NEW')
>        ->join('accounts', 'accounts.account_name =
> ```
>
> bugs.reported_by')
>              ->where('accounts.account_name = ?', 'Bob');
>
> ```
> $rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
> ```